# Как настроить логирование в SQL c помощью log4j в jboss 6.0.0?

Tags: java, sql, log4j, jboss, settings

Есть jboss 6.0.0 Final и сайт на java. Логирование включено, на данный момент вывод в виде файлов и дублирования в консоль. Нужно дублировать в SQL базу. Отсутствуют файлы log4j.xml или property. Проект не мой, нужно разобраться. Максимум что нашел ..../deploy/jboss-logging.xml. В него добавил:

```
<log4j-appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
        <error-manager>
            <only-once />
        </error-manager>
        <level name="DEBUG" />
        <properties>
            <property name="URL">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=myDB
            </property>
            <property name="driver">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
            </property>
            <property name="user">User</property>
            <property name="password">UserPass</property>
            <property name="sql">exec [dbo].[usp_insert_log_table]  'MyTestJBOSS','clientIP','serverIP','%p','%m'</property>
        </properties>
    </log4j-appender>

    <root-logger>
        <!-- Set the root logger priority via a system property, with a default 
            value. -->
        <level name="${jboss.server.log.threshold:DEBUG}" />
        <handlers>
            <handler-ref name="CONSOLE" />
            <handler-ref name="FILE" />
            <handler-ref name="DB" />
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>`
```

Если вместо properties сделать param:

```
 <log4j-appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
   <param name="URL" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=myDB"/>
   <param name="driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
   <param name="user" value="User"/>
   <param name="password" value="UserPass"/>
   <param name="sql" value="exec [dbo].[usp_insert_log_table] 'MyTestJBOSS','clientIP','serverIP','%p','%m'"/>
</log4j-appender>
```

Выдает ошибку:

> DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
>     Deployment "vfs:///D:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/all/deploy/jboss-logging.xml" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}param not found as a child of {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}log4j-appender in all: {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}level? {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}sub-handlers* {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}formatter? {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}loggers* {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}error-manager? {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}properties* {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}filter?

Пробовал удалить файл jboss-logger.xml. Все равно выводит в старом формате в консоль и файл, если что-то изменить, например патерн вывода в консоль - все работает. На локальном примере записи в SQL добавляются (т.е. настройки логин, пароль, база, хост, query - верны).

Comment: Данный метод логирования немного устарел. Предлагаю посмотреть в сторону [log4jdbc-log4j2](https://code.google.com/archive/p/log4jdbc-log4j2/) или [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy). Собственно при помощи них можно завернуть `DataSource` внутрь прокси, который будет заниматься логированием реальных sql'ников

Comment: Спасибо подумаю. Но к сожалению, проект существует и функционирует. Хотелось бы с минимальными изменениями достигнуть результат